# Python User Input control: How to allow the user to reenter one of the values he typed in?

Tags: python

I am writting a script that parses through localy saved archived log files for strings. After a feedback from a user, I would like to implement a feature allowing users to reenter a string they "messed up" in any manner. Is there a way to do this based on captured key combination for example in python? This is the list of user inputs I am collecting:

```
serverID = raw_input ("Description: ")
containerID = raw_input ("Description: ")
logtime = raw_input ("Description: ")
andor = raw_input ("Description: ")
string1 = raw_input ("Description: ")
string2 = raw_input ("Description: ")
string3 = raw_input ("Description: ")
string4 = raw_input ("Description: ")
afterIn = raw_input ("Description: ")
beforeIn = raw_input ("Description: ")
```

It is quite true that if they mess up afterIn and have to enter everything again, it may not be optimal, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an actual data structure for your data, which will make this task far, far easier:

```
fields = ["serverID", "containerID", "logtime", "andor"]

data = {field: raw_input("{}: ".format(field)) for field in fields}

while True:
    print("\nYou entered:")
    for key, value in data.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
    print("Please type the name of any field you wish to change, or nothing to continue.")
    field = raw_input("Correct a field?: ")
    if not field:
        break
    elif field in data:
        data[field] = raw_input("{}: ".format(field))
    else:
        print("Field name not recognised.")

print(data)
```

Here we use a dictionary to store the data. Note that dictionaries are unordered, so if the order matters you might want to use a `collections.OrderedDict`. Beyond that, we just loop until the user is happy with the data.